# What is difference between root and base directory?

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to use `shutils.py` , `make_archive` function.

here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#archiving-operations

but I can't understand the difference between root_dir and base_dir.

Here's a simple code using make_archive:

```
#!user/bin/python
from os import path
from os import curdir
from shutil import make_archive
# Setting current Directory
current = path.realpath(curdir)
# Now Compressing
make_archive("Backup", "gztar", current)
```

This will create an archive named Backup.tar.gz which contains a . Directory inside it.
I don't want the . directory but the whole thing inside in the archive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`root_dir` refers to base directory of output file, or working directory for your working script.

`base_dir` refers to content you want pack.

For example, if you have a directory tree like:

```
/home/apast/git/someproject
```

And you want to build a package for `someproject` folder, you can set:

```
root_dir="/home/apast/git"
base_dir="someproject"
```

If the contents of your tree is like following, for example:
/home/apast/git/someproject/test.py
/home/apast/git/someproject/model.py

The content of your package will acquire following structure:

someproject/test.py
    someproject/model.py

And your package file will be stored at:

```
/home/apast/git/<packfile-name>
```

Like doc shows, by default, root_dir and base_dir are initialized for your current working directory (cwd, or curdir). But, you can use it in a more flexible way.

Comment: Thanks a lot got it! any tip on how to get whole directory?

Comment: I fixed my description. these paramters refers to output. Sorry, I believe I started with a wrong solution. I will fix it to clear things

Comment: Which whole directory you want? May you exemplify better the expected result?

Comment: actually the description made the answer a bit confusing
the expected result is eg:
root_dir: /home/usr/project
which contains: dir1, dir2, dir3
which means base_dir contains 3 directories. how to add them all?

Comment: I will try something here and put in the answer. Soon I post it here

Comment: I will write it inside another answer, because it is a different question.

Comment: very helpful, the docs are not very clear

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider following dir structure:

```
/home/apast/git/web/tornado.py
/home/apast/git/web/setup.py

/home/apast/git/core/service.py

/home/apast/git/mobile/gui.py
/home/apast/git/mobile/restfulapi.py
```

We will try two snippets to clarify examples:
1. Defining base_dir
2. Without defined base_dir

1. Defining base_dir, we specify which directory we will include on our file:

   ```
   from shutil import make_archive
   root_dir = "/home/apast/git/"

   make_archive(base_name="/tmp/outputfile",
                format="gztar",
                root_dir=root_dir,
                base_dir="web")
   ```

   This code will generate a file called /tmp/outputfile.tar.gz with following struct:

   ```
   web/tornado.py
   web/setup.py
   ```
2. Running without base_dir, like following:

   ```
   from shutil import make_archive

   root_dir = "/home/apast/git/"

   make_archive(base_name="/tmp/outputfile",
                format="gztar",
                root_dir=root_dir)
   ```

   It will product a file containing:

   ```
   web/tornado.py
   web/setup.py
   core/service.py
   mobile/gui.py
   mobile/restfulapi.py
   ```

To define specific folders, maybe it will be necessary use some other technique, like gzip lib directly.

Comment: well I think it needs gzip lib directly as you say. using without base_dir will create a directory like:
/. => /web /mobile

Comment: Yes. It seens a little bit simple method. Otherwise, shutils is a great lib on dealing with os operations. Let's try something with other libs

Comment: Hey! Here seens a good solution for your issue! https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.add and https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.addfile . Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

cd in the root_dir... then tar the base_dir...
the docs makes me confuse too, read the code, that will make u clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing if you read the documentation but if you see it visually, it can help quite a bit.

The `root_dir` is the directory that you will be storing the file in.

If I were storing a file in `C:\Users\Elipzer\Desktop\MyFolder\`, That would be my `root_dir`.

The `base_dir` is the part added onto the `root_dir` so if I were storing it under my `MyFolder` in `...\MyFolder\MySubFolder\`, I would put that as the `base_dir`.

In many cases, there is no need to use these since you can just change the default directory to the directory that you want to store the file in and the `make_archive` function will just use the default directory as the `root_dir` and `base_dir`.